# UWP media element minimize pause

Tags: media, uwp, minimize, pause

When I minimize my media control app, it pauses the song/video.
How do i override this default function so that it keeps on playing?
Like in case of audio material it should keep on playing. Thanks in advance.

```
and i haven't tried anything already yet because i have no idea how to do it.
```

So please reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you using a MediaElement control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background playback task is implemented through `IBackgroundTask` with some added logic for audio services.

Unfortunately, there is no simple answer here. Instead, everything you need to know about background audio can be found here: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/01/13/the-basics-of-background-audio/